# HTML to word converting using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fileserver

I am trying to convert HTML to word (.docx) by using JavaScript. I am using this http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Export-Html-To-Word-Document-With-Images-Using-jQuery-Word-Export-Plugin.html plug-in for conversion. But this one is just converting every thing inside the HTML file. i mean with head tag all elements even with some content inside. output file looks like this

> Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Base:
>   file:///home/userprofile/JsWs/sample.html Content-Type:
>   Multipart/related; boundary="NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY";type="text/html"
>
> --NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8" Content-Location: file:///home/userprofile/JsWs/sample.html
>
> ```
>   <p>this is going to be paragraph </p>
>
>   </body></html>
> ```
>
> --NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY--

and **my html is**

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="FileSaver.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.wordexport.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $("a.word-export").click(function(event) {
                $("#export-content").wordExport();
            });
        });
        </script>
        <div id="export-content">

        <p>this is going to be paragraph </p>

        </div>

        <a class="word-export" href="javascript:void(0)"> Export as .doc </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Help me out how can i convert content of HTML in word.

Comment: I would suggest you to use an Api called Docverter. It allows you to convert HTML to DOCX.

Comment: or use https://github.com/evidenceprime/html-docx-js

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe this will open in Microsoft Word consistently on all devices. I've actually been working on a similar project [googoose](https://github.com/aadel112/googoose). It is meant to convert html to word documents as well. This does work for me on both my desktop and mobile phone version of Microsoft Word.

From my testing, Word will have problems with MIME header, and also the fact that there are no html, body tags, etc.

You should look into this project if you're still trying to do this. It should be supported for some time, as there's also a [Wordpress Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-googoose/) that uses googoose, which is linked to on the readme. The default action is to download the document on page load, but you can set it to be run onClick. For example,

Just include jquery and this plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://github.com/aadel112/googoose/jquery.googoose.js"></script>
```

Then to invoke onClick

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("a.word-export").click(function(event) {
            $(document).googoose({
                 area: '#export-content'
            });
        });
    });
```

With googoose you can include a table of contents, header, footer, automatic page numbering, etc. You can open the document up in Print view, set the margins, and page size. It's way more configurable than the referenced script, which is not configurable at all.

Comment: You just saved my day! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Aaron can we use external css here? or we just need to style our document inline?

Comment: @Aaron How can use your solution to export html text as `.docx` is it possible ?

Answer (score -3):

Try this,

```
function ConvertToHtml()
{
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "export-content";
    div.innerHTML = "<p>this is going to be paragraph </p>";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    $("#export-content").wordExport();
}
```