# Download webpage as Word document (docx)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ms-word

I have a wordpress page with some custom features in JS that people can save in a pdf format. Is there a way to allow people to download the page in docx (MS Word) as well? I tried searching for a solution but couldn't find much.

I'd like to have a button 'Download as docx' that generates a similar looking version as the pdf format.

Ideally, I'd like to do it in JS or find a WP plugin that offers the functionality.

Thanks for the help

Thomas

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with JavaScript.  There's a repository for it on Github [html-docx-js](https://github.com/evidenceprime/html-docx-js).  There's also a jquery plugin [googoose](https://github.com/aadel112/googoose).

You can also do it with a [WP plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-googoose/) that uses googoose.

Answer (score 0):

There is also this [plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Export-Html-To-Word-Document-With-Images-Using-jQuery-Word-Export-Plugin.html), FileSaver.js. You are able to export to .doc using jQuery

Comment: This might also be an option, however, googoose is a lot more configurable than this one.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222940/html-to-word-converting-using-javascript

Comment: Thanks Chava! I'll take a look